# Asynchronously wait for n things to happen

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#, semaphore

I'm looking for something like a `Semaphore` but that resolves after all the slots have been released.

Something like this:

```
use semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0,100)

anEvent.add(fun _ -> semaphore.Release(1) |> ignore);

async {
   do! thingThatCausesAnEventToFire100Times()
   //where 100 is the available slots instead of the timeout.
   let! thingsHappened = semaphore.WaitAsync(100) |> Async.AwaitTask
   thingsHappened |> should be True
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah if you know the answer in c# thats fine too :P

Comment: semaphores and stuff might have a problem with async (different threads) so as a first try I would just go simple lock/ref counter/manualresetevent

Comment: @Carsten Semaphores are meant for async/multithreaded use. From msdn for `SemaphoreSlim`: "Represents a lightweight alternative to Semaphore that limits the number of __threads__ that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently."

Comment: But `Semaphore` doesn't solve my problem :). For the refcount lock manualresetevent path I'd need state. Which I've sofar been able to avoid :).

Comment: that's why I wrote *might* - I would read the documentation really carefully for each of those if semaphores work: great - but monitors for example can fail horribly in async-contexts where you have an thread-switch in the middle: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do the *state-problem* ... your slot-counter will always be a state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a MailboxProcessor. How about this:

```
type SemaphoreCommand =
  |Release
  |Wait of AsyncReplyChannel<unit>

let semaphore slots =
    Agent.Start
    <| fun inbox ->
        let rec loop c (w:AsyncReplyChannel<unit> list) =
          async {
            let! command = inbox.Receive()
            match command with
            |Release -> if (c + 1) = slots then w |> List.iter(fun t -> t.Reply()) 
                        else return! loop (c + 1) w
            |Wait a -> return! loop c (a::w)
        }
        loop 0 []

let slotWaiter = semaphore 100

//Events will fill up slots
Release |> slotWaiter.Post
Release |> slotWaiter.Post

async{
  //Wait for all slots to be filled
  do! slotWaiter.PostAndAsyncReply(fun t -> Wait t)
  //All slots filled - continue
}
```

I'm not handling the case where you may not have registered a AsyncReplyChannel by the time all the slots are filled or the reset once all slots are filled but this is fairly trivial and I will leave it as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how trivial it turns out to be :). I wouldn't have thought of the `MailBoxProcessor` for this but I looks like a good fit.

Comment: The `w |> List.iter(fun t -> t.Reply())` is a no-op when there's when `w = []` , so there's no reason to account for the missing `AsyncReplyChannel` cancelation is easily achieved because `MailboxProcessor` is `IDisposable` so you can use `use slotAwaiter = semphore 100`